# Why does ?. is inevitable when calling a method although instance isn't nullable?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

I have to following variable declaration:

```
var baseItemList: MutableList<BaseDataItem>? = null
```

when writing the line:

```
baseDataItemsList?.get(position).getObjectTypeNum()
```

I'm getting an error saying that:

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type BaseDataItem?

**but**, *get* method doesn't return a *BaseDataItem?*, only a **BaseDataItem** since the **BaseDataItem** inside the brackets is **without a question mark**.
Can someone explain me this error, and why i have to add this question mark?

Comment: Your two code snippets do not line up. One refers to `baseItemList` and one refers to `baseDataItemsList`. But, assuming that those are really the same thing, `baseDataItemsList?.get()` could be `null`, because even though the *list* contains only non-`null` values, `baseDataItemsList` *itself* could be `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe I am not understanding something, but how can `baseDataItemsList?.get()` be null if it passes the `?.` check? Could you please explain

Comment: @Rey, you took my question :)

Comment: `?.` is not a "check". It returns `null` if the receiver (left-hand side) is `null`. So, if `baseDataItemsList` is `null`, `baseDataItemsList?.anyFunctionYouWantToCall()` will evaluate to `null`.

Comment: `baseDataItemsList?.get(...)` returns null if `baseDataItemsList` is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this code:

```
baseDataItemsList?.get(position)?.getObjectTypeNum()
```

The call `?.get(position)` returns the position if `baseDataItemsList` is not null, but otherwise returns null. So even though `baseDataItemsList.get()` would return a non-nullable `BaseDataItem` (only possible to call if `baseDataItemsList` is not nullable), the null-safe `baseDataItemsList?.get()` call returns a nullable `BaseDataItem?`, where the null condition indicates that `baseDataItemsList` is null. So you must use `?.getObjectTypeNum()` to account for this.

Side note: in my opinion combining `var` with a mutable collection is often a code smell, because you're making something mutable in two different ways, which makes it more error-prone to work with.

Comment: sorry but i still can't understand. If the check if baseDataItemsList? "passed" , why result of the get method should be also with ?. if there is any dangerous of null object anymore? Doesn't the chain (in run time) stopped when the first part of the safe calls returns a null? I thought that get method won't even run . I made the reference var and from MutableType since, in most time i will add/remove from list, but there situation that i wan't to repair the entire list with another list that i have a reference to

Comment: It’s not a pass/fail check. `?.` means if not null, return the result of calling this, else return null.

Comment: @Tenfour04, can you please tell me if *as* works differently and doesn't  take part in safe call chain? in the following code:  *(holder as ViewHolder)?.leagueNameTextView.text* , if *holder* isn't a *ViewHolder*, it mean that a null is return for all the expression on the left of *text* property, then trying to run *null.text* seems to be a problem, but the compiler doesn't inforce me to put a question mark before *text* property. Can you please explain me why?

Comment: `holder as ViewHolder` casts it to a non-null ViewHolder. It is an explicit, unsafe cast and if holder is null or not a ViewHolder, you'll get a NullPointerException or ClassCastException respectively at runtime. If you want to do a safe cast to nullable ViewHolder, you would use `holder as? ViewHolder`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks again :) I didn't notice that if forgot a question mark when usuing as?.. Thanks!!!  but the problem with *as?* that i have to do it for each time i'm using *holder*? The cast isn't being save? Or maybe to insert the *as?* into if statmement : if(holder as? ViewHolder != null)

Comment: Casting doesn't get "saved" unless you assign the result to a variable. But you can do it in an if statement's condition and it will apply inside the if statement's braces as a smart-cast. The reason it isn't saved is because a cast might be to a type that has does not completely overlap with the original variable's type, so it could theoretically be hiding methods. Also, casting is sometimes used to change which overload of a method is used when a parameter could fit either overload.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Kotlins scope functions, for example the `let` scope to avoid that warning:

```
baseDataItemsList?.let { baseDataItemList ->
  baseDataItemList.get(position).getObjectTypeNum()
}
```

That way you assert that baseDataItemList cannot be `null` inside the `let` scope. If you want to read more about that topic, [take a look into the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html)

Comment: Is it more "correct" way to do this, instead of the way i wrote it (with another safe call)?